# convert json to xml using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq in C#

Tags: c#, json, xml, serialization

I am trying to convert the following JSON to XML using class functions as DataMember. So far, it's going fine but now I am stuck at place where Json contains arrays of Objects.
[EDIT]
The json response after calling API

```
{
        "value": [
            {
                "locale": "zh",
                "value": "Name_in_China"
            },
            {
                "locale": "cs",
                "value": "Name_in_Czech"
            },
            {
                "locale": "bg",
                "value": "Name_in_Buglaria"
            },
        ]
    }
```

This is my Docs class for JSON to XML serialization

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Docs
    {


        static WebClient Client = new WebClient();
        public Docs()
        {

            
            Title = new List<Element>();
        }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Element> Title { get; set; }

    public List<string> get_localestring()
    {
         //some code calling and returning list of string objects from Json "locale"
    }
    public List<string> get_valuestring()
    {


         //some code calling and returning list of string objects from Json"value"
        }

     }
```

This is the Element class for storing data of "locale" and "value" strings

```
public class Element
{
    static WebClient Client = new WebClient();

    [DataMember]
    public List<string> locale { get; set; }

   [DataMember]
    public List<string> value { get; set; }

}
```

The main method where I am calling the serialization class

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                  
            
                        Docs obj = new Docs();
                        
                        obj.Title = new List<Element>() { new Element()
                             {
                                locale = obj.get_localestring()
                             },
                               new Element()  {
                                   value = obj.get_valuestring()
                                               } 
                                    };}
```

This is the output I am getting from my code

```
    <Docs xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/jsontoXML" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    
        <Title>
            <Element>
                <locale xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                    <a:string>zh</a:string>
                    <a:string>cs</a:string>
                    <a:string>bg</a:string>
                </locale>
                <value i:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
            </Element>
            <Element>
                <locale i:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
                <value xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                    <a:string>Name_in_China</a:string>
                    <a:string>Name_in_Czech</a:string>
                    <a:string>Name_in_Buglaria</a:string>
                </value>
            </Element>
        </Title>
        
    </Docs>
```

Following is the code that I am trying to achieve

```
</Docs>
          <Title>
          <element>
             <locale>zh</locale>
             <value>Name_in_China</value>
          </element>
          <element>
             <locale>cs</locale>
             <value>Name_in_Czech</value>
          </element>
          <element>
             <locale>bg</locale>
             <value>Name_in_Buglaria</value>
          </element>

       </Title>
</Docs>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You used `string title;` but I believe you need to do `List<Title> title;` where `Title` would be `public class Title { public string locale { get; set; } public string value { get; set; }}` with the appropriate `[DataMember]` attributes.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please also share with us your conversion logic.

Comment: I have edited my response to let you know how I am trying to get the required values